# Authentication in two websites using Firebase Authentication

Tags: node.js, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have two websites, the first 'bookstore.ltd.com', and the second 'first.bookstore.ltd.com'. I use the same Firebase authentication for both websites. I want to put a button on the menu of 'bookstore.ltd.com' that redirects the logged user to 'first.bookstore.ltd.com' and automatically logs him, so he doesn't have to re-log in.

I tried to send an id token as a query parameter, so when the user is redirected to 'first.bookstore.ltd.com' the id token will be used to authenticate the user and then send a custom token to log in the user. But the id token expiration time is 1 hour, which can be too much, because someone can copy one's id token and log himself in using it.
Is there any other way that I can archive this authentication, that can be safer?